# Disposing of all members in a loop

Tags: c#, reflection, dispose

I have a very large project with multiple pages, where each page has many `IDisposable` members.

I'm trying to figure out a way to dispose all the `IDisposable` members in a loop so I won't have to type `x1.Dispose(); x2.Dispose; ... xn.Dispose` on each class.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can write it in one method and use that multiple times if you need it. Or just use `using`.

Comment: Smart use of using block may remove the entire need of calling dispose itself.

Comment: If you can not use `using` block than just add all object to list `List<IDisposable>` and than loop through the list

Comment: Using block is inapplicable here

Comment: What is the structure of these pages? Which framework?

Comment: Of course you can, but the real question is, is that approach really efficient to do so?

Comment: @TomerSomething why?

Comment: @danish The scope of the members is for the entire lifetime of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection (not tested):

```
    public static void DisposeAllMembersWithReflection(object target)
    {
        if (target == null) return;
        // get all fields,  you can change it to GetProperties() or GetMembers()
        var fields = target.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        // get all fields that implement IDisposable
        var disposables = fields.Where(x => x.FieldType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IDisposable)));

        foreach (var disposableField in disposables)
        {
            var value = (IDisposable)disposableField.GetValue(target);
            if (value != null)
                value.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this. Although I would probably explicitly try and fetch the Dispose() method using GetMethod() and then run Invoke on the returning object, rather than casting it.

Comment: If you do go this route, please remember to wrap the calls to Dispose in a try catch to prevent leaking resources if one of the calls fails.

Comment: This is the approach i was looking for, but for some reason 'fields' is empty.. not sure why

Comment: @TomerSomething you need to add `BindingFlags.Instance`: `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance`

Comment: Thank you this seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just make sure that you create a list to hold them, and a try finally block to protect yourself from leaking them.

```
// List for holding your disposable types
var connectionList = new List<IDisposable>();    

try
{ 
    // Instantiate your page states, this may be need to be done at a high level

    // These additions are over simplified, as there will be nested calls
    // building this list, in other words these will more than likely take place in methods
    connectionList.Add(x1);
    connectionList.Add(x2);
    connectionList.Add(x3);
}
finally
{
    foreach(IDisposable disposable in connectionList)
    {
        try
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            // Log any error? This must be caught in order to prevent
            // leaking the disposable resources in the rest of the list
        }
    }
}
```

However, this approach is not always ideal. The nature of the nested calls will get complicated and require the call to be so far up in the architecture of your program that you may want to consider just locally handling these resources.

Moreover, this approach critically fails in the scenario where these Disposable resources are intensive and need to be immediately released. While you can do this, i.e. track your Disposable elements and then do it all at once, it is best to try to get the object lifetime as *short* as possible for managed resources like this.

Whatever you do, ensure not to leak the Disposable resource. If these are connection threads, and they are inactive for some period of time, it may also be wise to simply look at their state and then re-use them in different places instead of letting them hang around.

Comment: I am trying to avoid this manual adding of the members to a list, as i do not wish to go through every single page and assemble a list of all those members one by one

Comment: @TomerSomething - That is fine, please see the addition below with regards to that. It may be the best approach to simply wrap the instantiation of each Disposable instance in a using block and ensuring that its lifetime is as short as possible, and as narrowly scoped as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create method which will dispose all your disposable objects:

```
public void DisposeAll()
{
    x1.Dispose();
    x2.Dispose();
    x3.Dispose();
    . . .
}
```

and call it wherever you need it.